# Definition of the CESS_ESP tags

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm using the [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) CESS ESP data package and I've been able to use an adatpation
of the [spaghetti tagger](https://code.google.com/p/spaghetti-tagger/) and a `HiddenMarkovModelTagger` to pos-tag the sentence, how ever the tags that it produces are not at all like the ones used when tagging en_US sentences, here's a link to the [Categorizing and Tagging](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) documentation for NLTK, you'll notice that the tags used are uppercase and don't have any numbers or punctuation, some cess tags: `vsip3s0`, `da0fs0`.

Does some one know a reference that explains those tags?

### Sentence

> ¿Que es la programación orientada a objetos?

### Spaghetti Tagger

```
[('\xc2\xbfQue', None), ('es', 'vsip3s0'), ('la', 'da0fs0'), ('programaci\xc3\xb3n', None), ('orientada', 'aq0fsp'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('objetos', 'ncmp000'), ('?', 'Fit')]
[('\xc2\xbfQue', None), ('es', None), ('la', None), ('programaci\xc3\xb3n', None), ('orientada', None), ('a', None), ('objetos', None), ('?', None)]
[('\xc2\xbfQue', None), ('es', 'vsip3s0'), ('la', 'da0fs0'), ('programaci\xc3\xb3n', None), ('orientada', 'aq0fsp'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('objetos', 'ncmp000'), ('?', 'Fit')]
[('\xc2\xbfQue', None), ('es', 'vsip3s0'), ('la', 'da0fs0'), ('programaci\xc3\xb3n', None), ('orientada', 'aq0fsp'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('objetos', 'ncmp000'), ('?', 'Fit')]
```

### Markov Tagger

```
[('\xc2\xbfQue', 'sn.e-SUJ'), ('es', 'vsip3s0'), ('la', 'da0fs0'), ('programaci\xc3\xb3n', 'ncfs000'), ('orientada', 'aq0fsp'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('objetos', 'ncmp000'), ('?', 'Fit')]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `cess-esp` corpus is tagged using an old annotation system named **EAGLE** you can see it [here](http://www.ilc.cnr.it/EAGLES96/annotate/annotate.html). Hope this helps.