# Spanis POS tagger CESS, how can I implement this in my code

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, pos-tagger

I am working on this text `processing task, which involves getting the sentences tokenized and POS tagged in Spanish. I have written a code that works (following some online tutorials) but the POS tag is for English, and doesn't tag properly to Spanish words. So, my query is, how can I instruct python to use the Spanish Cess module?

I have already imported the NLTK tokenizer, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents and the  from nltk.corpus import cess_esp as cess

I would like to use this code, as it does save tuples of {token,POS} but just add the spanish pos tag to it. 
I would really appreciate any feedback.
Many thanks!

```
df['text']
tagger = cess
texts = df['text'].tolist()
tagged_texts = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, texts))
tagged_texts
df['POS'] = tagged_texts
pos_tag_sents( df['text'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist() )
df['POS'] = pos_tag_sents( df['text'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist() )
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus/20817106#20817106 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275398/nltk-spanish-tagger-results-real-bad

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256878/definition-of-the-cess-esp-tags